# Can I add text to my list numbering

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I have an ordered list like

1. content1
2. content2
3. content3

As it is for a road trip route, I want it to be:

Day 1 : content1

Day 2 : content2

Day 3 : content3

I can of course write it down as text, but i prefer having it as a list.
Is this possible?

Comment: where are you tried code  ?

Comment: show us what you have already done

Comment: What are you using ? You can always use JSON syntax. {'Day1': 'content1'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it *without positioning* the list items - resetting the list and letting `pseudo` elements to do the rest:

1. Reset the list style using `list-style-type:none` and `padding:0`
2. Now use an increment `counter` to get the required list numbering

See demo below:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: list;
}
ul li:before {
  content: 'Day ' counter(list) ' : ';
  counter-increment: list;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>content1</li>
  <li>content2</li>
  <li>content3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
ol {
  position:relative;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
ol li:before {
  content:"Day";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>content1</li>
  <li>content2</li>
  <li>content3</li>
</ol>
```

check this

Answer (score 0):

```
var routes = {}

//add to a list
routes.Day1 = 'Going Here!';
routes.Day2 = 'Resting';
//and keep adding so on

//to print/list the routes
console.log(routes);

//give it the tag and data
function add2html(tag, data) {
   var element = document.getElementById(tag);
   element.replaceWith(data);
};

// to add to day1
add2html('day1', routes.Day1)
```

Not sure what you're using so defaulting to javascript.
Then in html.

```
<!-- using <li></li> will give you numbers before -->
<ul id="day1"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by defining it as unordered list. 
Then in css define ul list-style as none.
Then use css before for every li as
li:nth-of-type(1) selector with content Day 1:, li:nth-of-type(2) selector with content Day 2: and position it appropriately.